# Excel vba read individual columns in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Need help to read selected columns ( actually column "A" and column "Z") from a CSV into an array. I know how to read full range into an array but my data has around 30 columns from which I require data only from few columns.

---

**Edit** from comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421908/9758194):

> *"How can I populate a single array with say Range("A1:A5") and Range("Z1:Z5")"*

And:

> *I was looking for an fast option without iteration.*

---

Thanks
Suji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filtering the columns out, you could also combine these two arrays:
maybe it's faster...

```
With Application
    aArr = .Transpose(Range("A1:A5").Value) 'make sure the range/columns are same size
    zArr = .Transpose(Range("Z1:Z5").Value)
    combinedArr = .Transpose(Array(aArr, zArr))
End With
```

Comment: Nice answer @Evr, haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

Sample range `A1:Z5`

---

<sub>***Full array:***</sub>

```
Dim arr as Variant: arr = Range("A1:Z5").Value
```

---

<sub>***Single column***, 1st column in below examples:</sub>

```
Dim arr as Variant: arr = Range("A1:A5").Value
```

or:

```
Dim arr As Variant: arr = [A1:A5]
```

or:

```
Dim rng as Range: Set rng = Range("A1:Z5")
Dim arr as Variant: arr = rng.Columns(1).Value
```

or:

```
Dim arr1 as Variant: arr1 = Range("A1:Z5").Value
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Application.Index(arr1, 0, 1)
```

---

<sub>***Multiple columns - Static rows***, 1st and 26th column in examples:</sub>

After your comment it became clear you want to populate a single array without looping with, for example column A and Z only. You can try the below:

```
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Application.Index(Range("A1:Z5").Value, [ROW(1:5)], Array(1, 26))
```

---

<sub>***Multiple columns - Dynamic rows***, 1st and 26th column in examples:</sub>

```
With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    Dim lr As Long: lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = Application.Index(.Range("A1:Z" & lr).Value, .Evaluate("ROW(1:" & lr & ")"), Array(1, 26))
End With
```

---

And there are many more ways to populate an array. However, you also need to ask yourself if that's what you need. You can access all items from any of the columns `A-Z` from your initial array through its X and Y index.

Comment: But how can I populate a single array with say Range("A1:A5") and Range("Z1:Z5")

Comment: I was looking for an fast option without iteration.

Comment: @Suji, please see the last edit for a way to do so without iteration =)

Comment: Dim arr As Variant: arr = Application.Index(Range("A1:Z5").Value, [ROW(1:5)], Array(1, 26))    ..... how can I change [ROW(1:5)] to contain all rows

Comment: Thanks. It worked however looks like creating seperate arrays for individual columns seemd to be faster.